# Allow dynamic parameter name for Angular ngResource call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngresource

I'm trying to use a custom Angular directive with a custom attribute, i.e. `:filterBy=:filter`. This is being done with a custom directive like this:

```
<foo filterBy=location filter=ABC></foo>
```

The service:

```
function Foo($resource) {
    return $resource(base + 'Foo');
}
```

The ngResource call:

```
var filterBy = attrs.filterBy;
var getSegments = Foo.get({filterBy: attrs.filter, limit: attrs.limit, offset: attrs.offset});
```

returns this:

http://localhost:8000/base/Foo?filterBy=ABC&limit=30 (notice it says "filterBy" instead of location")

It should be returning this resource instead:
http://localhost:8000/base/Foo?locations=Bar&limit=30

It seems the `filterBy` is being turned into a string in the ngResource call. I wan't it to use the value of the attrs.filterBy, but it doesn't like dot notation in the parameter value.

I've also tried this:

```
            var getFilter = function() {
                return attrs.filterBy;
            };
```

But when I do that, the resource URL turns into:

http://localhost:8000/base/Foo?getFilter=Bar&limit=30

Note the "getFilter" is the parameter now. So is there any way to create a custom parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
var filterBy = attrs.filterBy;
var params = {limit: attrs.limit, offset: attrs.offset};
params[filterBy] = attrs.filter;
var getSegments = Foo.get(params);
```

When you write `filterBy: value` then `filterBy` is an identifier. It's static. It has no relation whatsoever to any variable.

`params[filterBy] = attrs.filter;` on the other hand dynamically adds a property and the value within the brackets is an expression that can be resolved to a string. So it can be a variable.

Comment: @taco Then your attributes have no values yet. It's a separate problem that requires more information to be solved.

Comment: Yeah, once I get minute, I will post more info. Can't look at it now. Off the top of my head, attrs is some sort of object. Maybe $resource (ngResource) does something to get the attrs attribute names from this object.

Comment: @taco If `attrs` is the attributes object passed to the directive then it has to be `var filterBy = attrs('filterBy')`. But I think the attribute itself needs to be `filter-by`.